# Runtime variable for Oracle DATE type in Airflow

Tags: python, oracle, macros, airflow, cx-oracle

I'm trying to define task that requires a run-time parameter (let's call it 'batch_dt') in Apache Airflow.
I'm using **OracleStoredProcedureOperator** and the parameter of the procedure is of database type **date**.

```
procedure use_dates (
    i_date  in date,
    i_date2 in date,
    i_date3 in date
  );
```

However I'm having hard time defining this parameter as runtime variable. I could use an exactly formatted string for particular database but don't want to depend on current NLS setting in the database.

1. Airflow macros don't work `{{ dag_run.conf['batch_dt'] }}` or even 
   `{{ macros.datetime.strptime(dag_run.conf['batch_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d') }}`
   returns always a string resulting in

   ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
2. Using `to_date('{{ dag_run.conf['batch_dt'] }}', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` results in

   ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
3. When I define `date.today()` right in the task, it works fine, however I need to use run-time variable.

```
res_task = OracleStoredProcedureOperator(
    task_id = 'mytask',
    procedure = 'use_dates',
    parameters = 
        {"i_date": date.today(), #works but is not runtime
        "i_date2": "to_date('{{ dag_run.conf['batch_dt'] }}', 'DD-MM-YYYY')", 
        #returns a string "to_date('13-06-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY')" which results in ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
        "i_date3": "{{ macros.datetime.strptime(dag_run.conf['batch_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d' ) }}"
        #returns a string '2022-06-13 00:00:00' which results in ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
        }
    )
```

I was thinking about macro that returns a datetime object at runtime, however it seems macros can return only strings. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Since Python date type works (with the date.today() constuctor), can you convert the batch_dt column to Python date type? By the way it looks like you have been using two different formats; yyyy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yyyy. If the first one is correct you can use date.fromisoformat(dag_run.conf['batch_dt'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jinja templating**, used in Apache Airflow, **renders template fields as strings by default**. Therefore the result of your *strptime* method call is converted into string when rendered.

To override this behavior and be able to render native Python objects instead of plain strings, **you have to set DAG's *render_template_as_native_obj* option to True** (default option's value is False).

```
with DAG(
        'USE_DATES',
        description='TEST DATE INPUT RUNTIME DAG',
        ...
        render_template_as_native_obj=True
) as dag:
...
```

Your *OracleStoredProcedureOperator* call should now function as expected, passing Jinja rendered parameters as native Python objects (datetime in this case).

For more information please refer to official Airflow's documentation:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
call_procedure = OracleStoredProcedureOperator(
    task_id="call_procedure",
    do_xcom_push=False,        
    procedure="PROC_XYZ",
    parameters={"P_IN_WORK_DATE":date(2020, 5, 17)},
)
```

You can try 1) AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING:  true  2)  Set do_xcom_push=False .  Any of these should help you to pass date as input and also avoid error shown below.
Reference:- https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16386#issuecomment-1060017364

> ERROR - Could not serialize the XCom value into JSON. If you are using
> pickle instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle
> support for XCom in your *** config.